# How to select a base class at runtime depending upon an instance variable of parent class in Java?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, java-8

**Problem**: With the following classes, I am trying to select a base class at runtime depending upon an instance variable of parent class in Java. I believe there should be some fundamental property in OOPS which can help me achieve it which I am just missing.

```
    class Transaction{
       int id;
       enum transactionType;
    }

    class ATypeTransaction extends Transaction{
       /* bunch of instance variable specific to ATypeTransaction */
    }

    class BTypeTransaction extends Transaction{
       /* bunch of instance variable specific to BTypeTransaction */
    }
 /* The event can be triggered with any transactionType as declared in the enum TransactionType as each event would be associated with one transaction.*/
        class Event{
           int eventId;
           enum transactionType;
        }
```

Based on the transactionType, I have to prepare Transaction Payload and attributes will be different for different base classes as shown below.

**My Approach**: I am trying to use something like this (static polymorphism within switch-case) in an attempt to resolve the Transaction instance based on the transactionType.The problem with this approach is I am still not able to get hold of the child class. Rather I am getting parent class which stops me from accessing child class attributes.

```
public Transaction selectTransaction(TransactionType transactionType){
        Transaction transaction;
        switch(transactionType) {
            case = "AType":
                transaction= new ATypeTransaction();
                break;
            case = "BType":
                transaction= new BTypeTransaction();
                break;
        }
   return transaction;
}
```

Please help me out with this problem and provide a good design to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you know the type, why not just create the instance directly? Could you explain your motivation behind the enum overall?

Comment: I don't think that this code will compile as transaction object may not be initialized also why not change Transaction into interface

Comment: @akuzminykh edited. Please have a look.

Comment: @Zgr3doo looking for solution of  the design problem. Please provide an alternate solution as I have just put my raw idea around my approach and the given snippet for selectTransaction isn't the final code.

Comment: `enum transactionType;` is not a valid variable declaration. Likewise, `case = "BType":` is not a valid declaration for a `switch` statement. Further, it’s not clear what you want to achieve. To access the result of `selectTransaction` using artifacts of a specific subclass, the caller has to know and expect the particular subclass, which makes the entire `selectTransaction` method obsolete. The caller that knows which subclass is needed, can simply use `new KnownType()`.

Comment: 1/2
@ABHISHEKSRIVASTAVA what you are trying to create looks similar to factory pattern
but from your question I don't understand why you are trying to access child class attributes. Accessing attributes of object from outside is generally bad idea we use encapsulation to hide internal attributes of object from other objects. Ideally you would create interface of Transaction which would share set of methods common to all classes which implement this interface.

Comment: 2/2
And class which use this interface don't need to know which implementation its using. All logic would be performed inside of given interface implementation. I don't know the context but from names of your classes I think you may want to read more about Command pattern and factory pattern.
Check those links
https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method
https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command

Answer (score 1):

If you're set on selecting type of returned object using switch and enum type I think this will be the best solution:

```
public static enum TransactionType {
    AType,
    BType
}

public static class Transaction {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ATypeTransaction transA = selectTransaction(TransactionType.AType);
        BTypeTransaction transB = selectTransaction(TransactionType.BType);
        Transaction trans = selectTransaction(TransactionType.AType);

        transA.doA();
        transB.doB();
        ((ATypeTransaction)trans).doA();

        //The following will cause class cast exception
        ATypeTransaction transC = selectTransaction(TransactionType.BType);
        ((BTypeTransaction)trans).doB();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("Unchecked")
    public static <T extends Transaction> T selectTransaction(TransactionType transactionType){
        switch(transactionType) {
            case AType:
                return (T) new ATypeTransaction();
                break;
            case BType:
                return (T) new BTypeTransaction();
                break;
        }
    }
}

public static class ATypeTransaction extends Transaction {
    public void doA() {}
}
public static class BTypeTransaction extends Transaction {
    public void doB() {}
}
```

Unfortunately, unless you know if the result of `selectTransaction` method will be a specific superclass of class Transaction (so you can save it to a variable of a correct type) or if you check the type using operator `instanceof` (in case of variable of class `Transaction`), you'll risk JVM throwing `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The caller doesn't know which child class instance will be returned for selectTransaction call. So the solution does not fit well in my usecase.

Comment: You could still use my solution in that case. You'd need to store the result of `selectTransaction` in variable of type `Transaction`, then use `instanceof` operator to determine which subtype was returned, cast the result to a variable of the right type and process it accordingly.

Comment: True! But I am open to tweaking my existing design of Transaction to avoid the risk of getting ClassCastException.

Comment: @ABHISHEKSRIVASTAVA What do you mean by *"The caller doesn't know which child class instance will be returned"*? This is why you have the `enum`. If he knows the type, he knows the return type.

Comment: @ABHISHEKSRIVASTAVA Just skip the `enum` thing overall. Use the class itself. `public static <T extends Transaction> T selectTransaction(Class<T> transactionType) {` and `selectTransaction(ATypeTransaction.class)`.

Comment: @ABHISHEK SRIVASTAVA That's what `instanceof` is for - if you check the actual type before casting there will be no risk of getting `ClassCastException`

Answer (score 0):

put the business logic to your data:

```
class Transaction{
   int id;
   enum transactionType;

   public void handleTransaction() {
     //common code
   }
}

class ATypeTransaction extends Transaction{
   /* bunch of instance variable specific to ATypeTransaction */
   @Override       
   public void handleTransaction() {
     // access specific attributes
     super.handleTransaction();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think switch-cases in java only works with  byte, short, char, string and enum.
You could use the instance of Operator in an if statement. 
But maybe there are some better solutions when it comes to design patters.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you want your API to contain a method like `Transaction selectTransaction(...)`.

This assumes that your callers won't care about the concrete implementation of `Transaction`, but can do everything they want just using methods from the `Transaction` type, never needing anything specific from `ATypeTransaction` or `BTypeTransaction`.

Your question shows that this isn't true, the callers seem to need access to specific elements (methods or even fields) of the individual types.

There are two possible roads:

- Abandon the common parent class Transaction, and live with two independent classes `ATypeTransaction` and `BTypeTransaction`, or
- Find the use cases where the subtypes are handled differently, create an abstraction (abstract method) in the parent class, and implement it individually in the subclasses.